# Snow under Siberian High

Tags: meteorology, climate, snow

The Siberian High is a very strong anticyclone present over Siberia in the winter. Cities like Irkutsk lie at its very center, yet Irkutsk has 18-20 days of snow per month in the winter. Shouldn't we expect cloudless, clear skies under a strong high pressure, rather than two-thirds of the days having precipitation?

Comment: a source or a link had been usefull to this question.

Comment: Indeed historical precipitation probability in Irkutsk in the winter is [pretty low](https://weatherspark.com/y/115479/Average-Weather-in-Irkutsk-Russia-Year-Round#Figures-PrecipitationProbability) Perhaps this year was unusual.

Comment: Also here is an ESRL link to the [reanalysis plot](https://tinyurl.com/siberian-high) that shows the location of Siberian High

Comment: @Sim8132 - Hint- think of upper level potential vorticity anomalies having an impact on surface level phenomena. The phenomenon is inherently multi scaled and if the upper level PV anomaly is stronger than the lower level one you can have baroclincity and then wet weather.